# Is there a config file for monero on ubuntu / linux installs?

Tags: monerod, ubuntu

Currently the bitmonero folder resides in the home folder, but is there a config file I can just put this in vs having to start monerod with the --data-dir parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default configuration filename is **bitmonero.conf**. You should create it in the default data directory for your appropriate operating system.

Just add:

```
data-dir=[/path/to/your/new/dir]
```

On **Unix/Linux/macos** systems, the default directory is `~/.bitmonero`

Comment: is there a template of default values I can adjust?